# How to cache page with single dynamic block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I need to cache the home page of my Rails 4 website. It's all static, but with dynamic user state block on top. If user is not logged in, then he sees log in link, otherwise name and balance. For this reason we can't simply cache whole page. What the way can I go?

1. Cache whole page and add user state block after with AJAX;
2. Use fragment cache of whole page without this block;
3. Your version...

Comment: Small changes for grammar and simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Rails allows you to use dynamic cache keys.

For example you could use the current user's `id` as part of the cache key:

```
cache "homepage_balance_user_#{current_user.id}" do
  # stuff that belongs to a specific user
end
```

See. [Rails Guides about fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)

Comment: Yes, but I think, it's will be good to not use fragment cache, and use whole page cache (with nginx) instead. What do you think?

Comment: Afaik you cannot do that. You cannot cache the whole page if parts of the  page should be visible for specific users only. And since only Rails knows how the current user is, only Rails is able to decide what parts to include in the page and what parts not to show. Nginx doesn't have this information.

Comment: We can get this information by AJAX-request after nginx returned cache. Or not?

Comment: Sure, but than it isn't a Rails cache question anymore. Than it's more a question about how to load data via JavaScript.